# JavaScript won't load - html js

Tags: javascript, jquery

My JavaScript in head wont execute.
I have tried excluding alot of things to try and figure out why my JavaScript wouldn't execute with anything i had.
I have come to the conclusion that my JavaScript won't execute.
At the moment I only have a blank alert that should say "Loaded" but even that won't load.

This is the what I have in my code at the moment

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1   /DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html lang="nl" xml:lang="nl" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=Windows-1252" />
    <meta content="Windows-1252" http-equiv="encoding" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="nl" />
    <title>Micha J</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/JavaScript" />
    <script type="text/JavaScript"> 
    //<![CDATA[

        alert("Ready");

        //]]>
    </script>
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Hopefully someone will be able to help me with my problem and get it working.

Comment: Don't use self-closing script tags.

Comment: Alot of thanks for the fast response, it worked! 
I feel so stupid now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't self-close `<script>`. Use a full closing `</script>` tag here:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  alert("Ready");
</script>
```

See [squadette's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69984/4252741) citing the [XHTML 1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_3)

Comment: Thanks alot. It did the trick., SLaks also told me that this can't work. 

I feel stupid now.